# Axios GET not working in Safari browser

Tags: safari, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a simple method getInfo() request that is called on created() in the vue instance. It grabs data from an external api and renders it on the page.

```
created() {
    this.getInfo();
},
methods: {
    getInfo() {
        let vm  = this;
        let url = [my api url];
        axios.get(url)
          .then(response => {   
              console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
          })
    },
```

The method works perfectly fine in Chrome, but is completely ignored in Safari (High Sierra, 10.13.2) . Any ideas why this may be occurring? No console errors.

Comment: Only guess would be that it doesn't support the method shorthand but I would have expected some script error. You could try `getInfo: function() {...}`.

Comment: Are you seeing a network request in the network tab? Are you transpiling using a build tool?

Comment: @JamesWestgate - In Safari, i only get a network request for the call on the first load, but if i walk through the steps again it doesn't appear and is no longer called. Transpiling with Webpack.

Comment: @Bert - issue still seems to occur without the method shorthand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok was able to resolve the issue, see code below. I refactored the axios call, and added some new options. The key was to add a cache-buster to the URL in the axios call. Safari does not do this automatically. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
    getInfo: function () {
        let vm  = this;
        let url = let url = [my api url];

        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: url + '?nocache=' + new Date().getTime(), // Safari fix
            withCredentials: true
        })
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
          })
    },
```

Comment: Does this work for all Servers/ is this a common practice? I use a nginx

Answer (score 9):

For me I found that if I add `/` to the end of my endpoint, e.g. `/users/` instead of `/users` it works in Safari and it wasn't before it

Comment: you just saved me after 6 days of pulling hair